# JavaScript using a variable instead property

Tags: javascript

I have a function

```
set(prop, value) {
    prop(value);
}
```

But it tell me prop is not a function and it's normal.

What I want is:

```
set('foo', 'bar') {
    foo('bar');
}
```

How could I do please ? I need some help !

Comment: Pass function as is, `set(foo, 'bar')`

Comment: What are you passing to `set()`?  The syntax of "what you want" doesn't make much sense to me, you're using string literals where I would expect function parameters.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the function instead of its name ?

Pass directly the function and call it inside your set method:

```
set(foo, 'bar') {
    foo('bar');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If foo is a global function and you are running this in browser you could use as follows:-

```
function set(arg1, arg2){ 
    window[arg1](arg2); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is very little info on what exactly you want to do and the context of your code. This way or another you have to tell JS what your function is doing. My take on your problem below:

```
//declare prop as function
var prop = function(x){
    //do whatever you need with it
    return x;
};

//set is a function?
function set(prop, value) {
    return prop(value);
}

console.log(set(prop, 'passed value'));
```